# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: javascript

Getting my API data via Postman works fine but when running following code in my js application I get an error:  `Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer mybearertoken");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Id", "56afb645-6084-4129-6469-08d91f4770af");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://myapi.com/api/Konfigurator/GetProjekt", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: You said `method: 'GET'` and `body: formdata`.  What is unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method);

> If this’s request method is `GET` or `HEAD`, then set body to null.

GET and HEAD requests do not have a body, so all parameters should be in the URL.

As for Postman concern, technically, you can send any HTTP request with a body in it as long as the http web server can read it. [Nothing prevents get request of having a body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3). This is an ongoing discussion regarding limitation of how much query string can URL parameters contain and how people need to supply complex parameters into a GET request.

However, some people just tend to keep it as a `best practice` by utilizing other http methods for body and other went along with it.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding `body` to a http GET request.
change your method to POST and everything will be fine. (if you handle it correctly on server)

Example:

```
var url = "/api/route";
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("id", "123");

// before - if not defined, the default method value is 'get'
var options = { body: formData };

// after - set method to 'post'
var options = { body: formData, method: "post" };

var response = await fetch(url, options);
var data = await response.json();
```